# Possible to test if each value in a text string equals an integer value?

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql, postgresql-9.3

Is it possible to test whether each value in a text string (`v1`) equals an integer value (`t2.variable`)?  The desired outcome is to `SUM` all values from entries where the integer matches one of the text string values.

e.g.

```
SELECT string_agg(id::text, ', ') INTO v1
    FROM t1;

SELECT SUM(value) INTO v2
    FROM t2
    WHERE v1 = t2.variable;
```

Comment: Match to all .. with what intent? The sum equals one of them? All of them? Or each individual value equals one of them? Don't present the supposed solution, *present the problem first*. Most probably, there is is a better approach again. Plus, we need to see table definitions to know types and other details. `\d tbl` in psql. Obviously, you are approaching problems in a "procedural" way, coming form other programming languages. Typically, there is a superior set-based approach in SQL.

Comment: The goal is for the query to `SUM` all values returned by the second `SELECT` statement.  The problem is how can the second `SELECT` statement compare the single value in `t2.variable` to multiple values in the `v1` string.

Comment: Please *edit* the question with basic information. It is still unclear to me how to compare *exactly*, btw. "compare" is ambiguous.

Comment: By "each" you mean "at least one" or "all"? Also, you are still keeping the table definitions a secret. It also depends on possible NULL values and exact data types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guessing you want to test if *any* row in `t1` exists with a matching `id`.
You *can* do that with the [**`ANY`** construct](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-comparisons.html#AEN18486):

```
SELECT SUM(value) INTO v2
FROM   t2
WHERE  t2.variable = ANY ((string_to_array(v1 , ', '))::int[]);
```

Assuming `integer` values.
But it would be extremely inefficient to do so. Converting types back and forth, aggregating, unnesting again. Error-prone and expensive. Instead, test with an `EXISTS` semi-join directly:

```
SELECT SUM(value) INTO v2
FROM   t2
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM t1 WHERE t1.id = t2.v1);
```

Comment: Please provide some kind of explanations too while answering a question.

Comment: @Lal: Read some of my answer, I usually provide more explanation than most. But I am certainly not adding explanation while the question is still undefined.

Comment: oops..actually this answer was flagged as low quality..Dint know about the scenario..Sorry..